# How can I use a variable that is defined in a turtle context in a patch context?

Tags: netlogo

How can I use a variable that is defined in a turtle context in a patch context ?
This is my code (I simplified it) :

```
turtles-own [a]
patches-own [b]

to add-turtles
create-turtles 2 [ set shape "turtle" set color gray set size 2 ] 
ask turtles [
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
set a random 10 ]
end 

to function 
let beta0 0.4
let beta1 0.9

ask turtles [ 
 ask patches in-radius 8 [ 
  set pcolor red
  set b beta0 + beta1 + a ] ]
end
```

In this code, each of two turtles has a value of "a". I would like that patches in a radius of 8 around the first turtle obtain the value of "a" specific at this turtle + beta0 + beta1. It's the same thing for the second turtle.

I have a error message : you can't use A in a patch context, because A is turtle-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with myself : `[a] of myself`

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've seen Marine's answer, and after your updates, this is making more sense to me now.

Marine suggests using `[a] of myself`.  That works, and is probably what I would suggest too. But here's another option, using `let`:

```
ask turtles [
  let center-a a
  ask patches in-radius 8 [
    set b beta0 + beta1 + center-a
  ]
]
```

Comment: I improved my code. I have "patches" nested inside "turtles". Patches should get access to the turtles variables of turtles situated in one of these patches.

Comment: Updated now that I understand better.